# setup Magento with MAMP PRO + SSL

Tags: error, htaccess, mamp

I am trying to setup Magento on my recently purchase MAMP Pro, hoping to setup a testing environment, similar to production site.

1. I added my server name as div.example.com
2. use port 80, 443,3306 www/mysql
3. use self-signed SSL, and put in my project root folder
4. I tested with a simple index.php with hello world call, everything looks ok
5. I copy the magento file, I got a 403 error

I am pretty sure, it have to do with the .htacess file magento come with anyone have any experience with it? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few things you can do. In your `.htaccess` make sure `RewiteBase` [is uncommented](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/.htaccess#L123). Also when you unzipped the magento install you might need to adjust the file permissions. e.g

```
find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644
find ./ -type d | xargs chmod 755
chmod -Rf 777 var
chmod -Rf 777 media
```

Hope this helps! :)